# Flex mobile automated testing

Tags: android, apache-flex, testing, flex-mobile

I develop Flex mobile applications (specifically Android) and would like to know what tools can be used to automate the application testing. Every piece of information will be deeply appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Free** tools that will work for testing Flex on mobile:

- [***fMBT***](https://01.org/fmbt/blogs/ask/2013/fmbt-android-ui-testing)
- [***Sikuli***](http://www.sikuli.org)

---

**Commercial** tools (most of them include trial):

- [***SeeTest***](http://experitest.com)
- [***EggPlant***](http://www.testplant.com/eggplant/)
- [***Ranorex***](http://www.ranorex.com)

---

> **Few recommendations:**
>
> - *Free:* **fMBT** is quite new one, but looks very promising.
> - *Commercial:* **SeeTest** is very popular tool at the moment.
>
> — I recommend to look at this two ones first of all.

Comment: Hello Dmitry, have you used any of these? Do you have any recommendations? Appreciated.

Comment: I've updated an answer. SeeTest is very popular and powerful. Among free tools fMBT looks very promising. I recommend to look at this couple first.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, I already looked into them but SeeTest is incredibly expensive (U$3.500), as is Ranorex, so I'm left with fMBT and Sikuli. Do you have any experience on any of them? or any comments?

Comment: No, almost no my own experience unfortunately. I haven't performed Flex testing on mobile yet.